# Code Won't Drop Students From a Course [Java]

Tags: java, class, oop, object

The same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818374/logic-error-in-adding-and-dropping-students-java), but I think I'm getting closer to solving it.

My code, in a nutshell, has two courses, and I have to drop a few students from each of them, and then clear the second course entirely. This code is done using two classes.

This is what I have so far:

```
/*
Program description:
Starting with listing 10.5 and 10.6 below, you are to modify the two source
files to:

Course.java:


 add method increaseArray().
Increase the array when students are added by 1, (hint utilize
System.arraycopy method ). Then add the student to the last location. I
would suggest you set the size of the “students” array to a size initially
of zero, so when the any student is added, your code to increase the
array will be triggered.

add method dropStudent().
Drop student would need to find the String match by iterating on the
students array using the .equals String method. When a match is found,
remove that entry by assigning the next student into the match location,
and do for all the remaining students (effectively shift remaining
students by one ). Also you would have also decrement the
numberOfStudents count.

 add method clear().
Iterating on the students array assign all to null and set the
numberOfStudents count to 0.
TestCourse.java:
You need to test your new methods; this is done by modifying listing 10.5 to
meet the requirements of assignment which are:

Create a two courses
Add six students to the first, three students to the second
Remove the first two student from course one
Remove the second student from course two
Display students in both classes
Clear the second course
Display students in both classes


Add a static method to TestCourse that handles printing the students in a
class. This method receives the reference of the course and the course
number. This way, you just call the method to print out the students.
 */

public class Course {
private String courseName;
private String[] students = new String[100];
private int numberOfStudents;

public Course(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public void addStudent(String student) {
    students[numberOfStudents] = student;
    numberOfStudents++;
}

public String[] getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public int getNumberOfStudents() {
    return numberOfStudents;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public void dropStudent(String student) {

    int IndexOfStudentToDrop = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        if (students[i].equalsIgnoreCase(student)) {
            IndexOfStudentToDrop = i;
            if (IndexOfStudentToDrop != -1) {
                for (i = IndexOfStudentToDrop; i < numberOfStudents; i++)
                    students[i] = students[i+1];
            } // end if found
            // decrement number of students by 1
            numberOfStudents--;
        }
    }

}

public void clear() {

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i ++){
        students [i] = null;
    }
    numberOfStudents = 0;

}

public void increaseArray() {
    if (numberOfStudents >= students.length) {
        String[] temp = new String[students.length * 2];
        System.arraycopy(students, 0, temp, 0, students.length);
        students = temp;
    }



} // end of increaseArray()

public String toString ()
{
    String output = "";
     output += getCourseName()+ (getNumberOfStudents() + "students");
        for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfStudents(); i++) {
                output += "\n("+ (i + 1)+")"+ students [i];
            }
    return output;

}
}
```

and

```
public class TestCourse {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create two courses
    Course course1 = new Course("Data Structures");
    Course course2 = new Course("Database Systems");

    // introduce the program
    System.out.println("Creating Two Courses");
    System.out.println("Adding 6 students to course 1");
    System.out.println("Adding 3 students to course 2");


    // add six students to course1
    course1.addStudent("\n1: Tom Servo");
    course1.addStudent("\n2: Joel Robinson");
    course1.addStudent("\n3: Mike Nelson");
    course1.addStudent("\n4: Pearl Forrester");
    course1.addStudent("\n5: TV's Frank");
    course1.addStudent("\n6: Zap Rowsdower");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();




    // add three students to course2
    course2.addStudent("\n1: Tom Servo");
    course2.addStudent("\n2: Crow T. Robot");
    course2.addStudent("\n3: Zap Rowsdower");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();



    // output to the console
    System.out.println ("Number of students in Course 1: " + course1.getNumberOfStudents() + " Students are: ");
    String [] students = course1.getStudents();

    for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++)
        System.out.print(students[i]);


    System.out.println ();
    System.out.print("Number of students in Course 2: " + course2.getNumberOfStudents() + " Students are: ");
    String [] students1 = course2.getStudents();

    for (int i = 0; i < course2.getNumberOfStudents(); i++)
        System.out.print(students1[i]);

    // output to the console how many students will be dropped from each class
    System.out.println("dropping 2 students from course 1");
    System.out.println("dropping 1 student from course 2");


    // drop some students.
            course1.dropStudent("Tom Servo");
            course1.dropStudent("Joel Robinson");
            System.out.println ("\nNumber of students in Course 1: " + course1.getNumberOfStudents() + " Students are: ");

            course2.dropStudent("Crow T. Robot");
            System.out.println("\nNumber of students in Course 2: " + course2.getNumberOfStudents() + " Students are: ");

    // clear course2, but keep course1 as it currently stands
            System.out.println("\nclearing course 2 course 2");
            course2.clear();

            System.out.println("\nNumber of students in Course 1: " + course1.getNumberOfStudents() + " Students are: " );
            System.out.println("\nNumber of students in Course 2: " + course2.getNumberOfStudents() + " Students are: ");
    }

}
```

This is what the output is supposed to look like:

```
Creating Two Courses
Adding 6 students to course 1
Adding 3 students to course 2

Number of students in Course 1: 6 Students are: 
1: Tom Servo
2: Joel Robinson
3: Mike Nelson
4: Pearl Forrester
5: TV's Frank
6: Zap Rowsdower

Number of students in Course 2: 3 Students are: 
1: Tom Servo
2: Crow T. Robot
3: Zap Rowsdower

dropping 2 students from course 1
dropping 1 student from course 2

Number of students in Course 1: 4 Students are:
1: Mike Nelson
2: Pearl Forrester
3: TV's Frank
4: Zap Rowsdower

Number of students in Course 2: 2 Students are:
1: Tom Servo
2: Zap Rowsdower

clearing course 2 course 2

Number of students in Course 1: 4 Students are:
1: Mike Nelson
2: Pearl Forrester
3: TV's Frank
4: Zap Rowsdower

Number of students in Course 2: 0 Students are:
```

But this is what happens instead:

```
Creating Two Courses
Adding 6 students to course 1
Adding 3 students to course 2




Number of students in Course 1: 6 Students are: 

1: Tom Servo
2: Joel Robinson
3: Mike Nelson
4: Pearl Forrester
5: TV's Frank
6: Zap Rowsdower
Number of students in Course 2: 3 Students are: 
1: Tom Servo
2: Crow T. Robot
3: Zap Rowsdowerdropping 2 students from course 1
dropping 1 student from course 2

Number of students in Course 1: 6 Students are: 

Number of students in Course 2: 3 Students are: 

clearing course 2 course 2

Number of students in Course 1: 6 Students are: 

Number of students in Course 2: 0 Students are:
```

As you can see, my code won't drop students when I need it to (though clearing doesn't seem to be a problem). I'm aware my formatting is messed up, but that isn't my primary concern, and I could fix that on my own. Aside from formatting, the dropping students is my only problem, and if I could just have help with that, I can take it from here.

Comment: Where is your `Student` class? Particularly curious about the method for comparison of students (`equalsIgnoreCase`)

Comment: Student is the name of the string that is used to drop students from a certain class.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this does not work is the following: You are putting strings like `1: Tom Servo` with the number, and trying to remove them like `course1.dropStudent("Tom Servo");`

If you would either remove the `1:` when adding a `Student`, or you would try to remove them as:

```
course1.dropStudent("1: Tom Servo");
```

I'm certain that it'd work.

Comment: Alright, it's counting the number of students after doing the 'dropStudent', but it won't list the students after the drops have been made.

Comment: Never mind, I just needed to reuse the for loop to print out the new list of students.

Comment: Was this ultimately the issue? If so, and it's fixed, i'd kindly ask you to close the question by accepting the answer. :)